# PHP / JS - Echo Js function Notification after PHP curl post

Tags: javascript, php, notifications, alert

I'm trying to show a Javascript function, which contains a alert/notification after my PHP Curl post went through.

Any idea how to get this working?

My Javascript:

```
<script>
    $('body').pgNotification({
        style:'bar',
        message: 'added',
        position:'top',
        type:'success',
        timeout:'6000'
    }).show();
</script>
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.site.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'parameters to pass');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookiefile';
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Now I want to show the Javascript Notification after the PHP curl post is done.

Sadly I can't simply use a `echo 'HTMLCODE';` to show a notification. I need the timeout function in it.

I appreciate every kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

Expecting that you are not calling `CURL` through `AJAX`. Just echo your javascript function if `CURL` response is what you want it to be.

**Javascript**

```
function showNotification(){
  $('body').pgNotification({
      style:'bar',
      message: 'added',
      position:'top',
      type:'success',
      timeout:'6000'
  }).show();
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.site.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'parameters to pass');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookiefile';
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($response == 'whatever it should return'){
        echo "
        <script>
            // Run this if page is loaded
            // Probably using jQuery?
            $(document).ready(function(){
                showNotification();
            });
        </script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Tried your way, sadly the notification wont show up :(

Comment: Was the `script` part echo-ed in html? Any errors on `console`? Are you using jQuery?

Comment: No script part will be shown in the HTML. Console Log shows: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Comment: Your if statement is failing. Check if your response is what you are expecting. If you are using jQuery with `noConflict()`, replace `$` accordingly.

Comment: Even if i take out the whole if request, it wouldnt show up

Comment: Do i need to add something else? Because incase i show this <script></script> tag at the bottom, it would show up. Otherwise in the Content it wont.

Comment: Is this all on one page? You are NOT using AJAX, right? It has to `echo` content if you don't have `if` statement.

Comment: It's all in one template. Also it shows up now, but the code is just loading at the bottom of the code. Actually it's showing in the middle of the code. Ill try to add the php now on the bottom. The error in the console comes by this line: $('body').pgNotification({ Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: If you are using jQuery, replace `$` with `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test() {
  $('body').pgNotification({
    style:'bar',
    message: 'added',
    position:'top',
    type:'success',
    timeout:'6000'
  }).show();
}
```

```html
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.site.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'parameters to pass');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookiefile';
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
echo '<script>test();</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Tried your way also, sadly the notification wont show up :(

Comment: This is similar to:
function test() {
     alert('test');   
}
<?php
    echo '<script>test();</script>';
?>

And it works 100%. If it doesn't that means your have some error, try to validate your website here: http://validator.w3.org/
Also, make sure you load jquery before this function.